# Hibernate, save 1Millon entities, consume A LOT of memory

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, transactions, save

I have a problem with hibernate+java. I have a class that take a file, parse it to CSVRecord and then by processRecord () convert each line to an object (classA), then I try to find that object in my DB, if I had I update the object "else" i save it for the first time.
After 1000 lines processed I commit the transaction, clean the session and start over the transaction.
The problem is when start to process the file (1 Million records)  the memory java consume start to grow a lot (2Gb)and at the end don't release, so if i need the method process another file i have not memory, I never had a memory exception yet, because i still have memory, but it is not going to be the same in the server.
I try to do the same code using flush () and clear (), but didn't wort neither,
The code is something like this:

```
db = new DB();
db.open();
trn = db.session().beginTransaction();

for (CSVRecord line : lines) {
         try {
           if ((classA = processRecord(line)) != null) {
             classB b = findObject(classA);

             if (b != null) {
               db.session().update(b);
             } else {
               db.session().save(classA);
             }

             if (recordNumber % 1000 == 0) {
               trn.commit();
               db.session().clear();
               trn = db.session().beginTransaction();
             }

             recordNumber++;
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
}

db.close();
```

Comment: maybe an easy solution is to just handle 1000 per transaction and close and start a new one etc.. ??

Comment: Yes, I tried it and kind of it works, but the idea wasn't accepted by the project manager, I don't fell good with idea neither because I'm going to open and close too many times the DB.

Comment: There are solutions online, streaming the file. I found this for example: http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to read the article, but the problem is not reading the file, that works, ant then I tried reading line by line instead of  using CSVRecord, but still the same.
I think I'm doing something wrong at the commit or save/updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stateless session as it doesn't have a persistence context cache which improves performance compared to method you are using currently

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    session.insert(yourentiry);
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Definitely I'm going to read and try it! Tomorrow I let you know how was it